# In google cloud Compute engine persistent disk v/s cloud storage which should i use and why?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Hello all I am doing a start up and for cloud server I am using google cloud platform to launch my android app. Now I was reading through google's docs, but I can't figure out how I am going to put my scripts on google cloud because I came across two things **Cloud Storage**  and other one was **Compute engine's Persistent disks**. I also google this question and it leads me here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#pdgcs. I read it, but now I am more confused because initially I thought that when I am going to create my instance then there there will be a memory selection and also disk selection field so I thought all of my data which are my NOSQL data and both my scripts are going to be inside my Compute Engine disk section, but as I read about this cloud storage section so now I am wondering why even they have these two types of storage wouldn't it be a lot easier to put storage section only at one place?

Please if anyone know about this please answer also if you think this question is very less detailed then sorry I am a newbie in cloud server hosting so I don't know anything about this, it will be really appreciatable if you can just enlighten me here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is whether you need global read/write access to this data or whether each Compute Engine instance will read/write its own data individually.

If you need global access, Cloud Storage is the solution. If only local access is needed, go with Persistent disks as it has lower latency.

From what you described, it looks to me that you probably want to go with Persistent disks.

Comment: And this would be one of the reasons why _Cloud Storage_ costs much more than the _Persistent HDD_.